# Netbeans won't recognize Glassfish 4 installation

Tags: java, netbeans, glassfish

I have been trying to add Glassfish 4 server to my list of available servers on Netbeans (7.2.1) but it always says "invalid server installation". I have been following these steps ...
 1. Open Netbeans as administrator 
2. Open Tools -> Servers 
3. Click "Add Server" button 
4. Choose GlassFish Server 3+ 
5. Specify a name as "GlassFish" 
6. Choose the installation folder location - C:\glassfish4

Anyone else had this problem? Have a solution that might work? I saw some entries here regarding similar troubles with Glassfish 3.2 but the solutions didn't work here.

Comment: I don't think NB 7.2 already supports GF4, that one was added in 7.4 I think.  You should upgrade your Netbeans installation (it's easy, the new version will pick up all the old version's settings, and they can easily coexist should you want to keep the old one around eg for GF2 based projects).

Answer (score 0):

Check this link, Netbeans IDE 7.2.1 supports till 3.1.2.2.

https://netbeans.org/community/releases/72/relnotes.html

Use the higher version.
Check this link out: https://glassfish.java.net/ide.html